# Navigating to a specific fragment in a flow document from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, flowdocument

I have a WPF page used as an input form which contains a number of controls on one side, and a flow document reader on the other.

I want to set the content of this document reader to a specific part of a flow document which is loaded when the form is loaded, (via a loaded event).

I have found an article explaining how to do this, using fragments, but the examples shown are only expressed in XAML.

In my case I need to update the document property of the flow document reader when the user gives focus to one the controls (I have wired up the events already) therefore I need to do this in the code behind rather than XAML.

I have tried setting the document property to:

```
Document#Control_Sport
```

where Document is the name of XAML flow document and Control_Sport is the name of the fragment I need to navigate to.

However this gives an error, it doesn't like the hash sign being there.

I tried looking on MSDN but its XAML only. Is there a way I can do this through code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Felix,

Link to MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#FragmentNavigation

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to any `Block` within a `FlowDocument` by calling `Block.BringIntoView`.

Comment: How exactly do I do this? Could you give an example, I found block as a property of the flowreader, flowreader.document and of the flowdocument used in the flowreader.

thanks, felix

Comment: The elements you add to FlowDocument are of type Block. Things like Paragraphs, Sections etc. You can call BringIntoView on any block element to make it show in a FlowDocumentReader, FlowDocumentPageViewer, etc.

Comment: Right the paragraphs in my flow document are all named as follows;

    <Paragraph Name="Control_Sport">
        <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18">Fixture: Sport</Run>
            <LineBreak /><LineBreak /><Run FontStyle="Italic">Examples: Curling, Talking</Run>
    </Paragraph>

How do I then bring this section in view? Like this,

    FlowScrollReader.document = Document.BringIntoView.Control_Sport"

Cause that doesn't work! Sorry to keep asking, I'm new to WPF and the examples microsoft give are either in XAML or completely useless.

thanks,

Comment: If you give the element a name: <Run FontWeight="Bolt" FontSize="18" x:Name="sport"> then it will generate a member of that name in the code which you can use. So in this case, sport.BringIntoView()

Answer (score 1):

First, create a Frame object inside your Page or Window object.  Setting the `JournalOwnership` property to `"OwnsJournal"` will give the document its own navigation bar (forward and back arrows plus a history).  You will probably need to add additional parameters to size and locate the frame within your document as well, but I didn't include them in my example since I don't know what your app requires:

```
<Frame Name="MyFrame" JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal" />
```

Then, create a pack URI for your document fragment.  This document is assumed to be in the same directory as the application's executable; you will need to add more to the path to navigate to the directory where the document resides in your project:

```
Uri MyUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyXamlDocument.xaml#MyFragment");
```

Then, navigate to it from inside your button's Click handler or whatever other means you like to initiate the navigation:

```
MyFrame.Navigate(MyUri);
```